# In SSMS can I select against temp tables created in the SPROC I'm debugging while the debugger is paused

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

In SSMS can I select against temp tables created in the SPROC I'm debugging while the debugger is paused?

Something like in the immediate window of Visual Studio?
When I try SELECT in the command window, it doesn't work. IS this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258255%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

> **Temporary Tables**
>
> You can create local and global
>   temporary tables. Local temporary
>   tables are visible only in the current
>   session; global temporary tables are
>   visible to all sessions.

You will notice from SSMS, that each tab has a different session id, so, I dont think this is possible, unless you make these global.

Comment: I was worried about that -- I was hoping I could run a query against the scope of the debugger.

Comment: +1. Honestly, as I couldn't see any other way, I simply had to copy & paste my client scripts that created and populated temps, before running the actual script being debugged at the time. Not that I would like to promote such primitive actions, but I still do not know about a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:
Create the temp table, say #tmp1 outside of the stored procedure
Inside the stored procedure you can create the tmp table, if it doesn't exist. I'm not sure if that step is required.

Now after calling the stored procedure, you can select from the temp table.

**Note:**
I'm using this at work, but I'm not proud of this trick anymore. In a distributed development environment it is difficult to ensure, that both definitions of the temp table are identical. Maintenance can become a headache.

Answer (score 0):

I built a few stored procedures which allow you to query the content of a temp table created in another session.

See [sp_select](https://github.com/FilipDeVos/sp_select) project on github.

The content of the table can be displayed by running `exec sp_select 'tempdb..#temp'` from no matter which session.